# .net core 3.0 authorize attribute with Policy, AuthenticationSchemes

Tags: c#, authentication

I am trying to implement two authentication schemes in my app. In controller with authorize attribute, I set scheme that the controller has to use to authenticate. 
register auth:

Startup:

```
 public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureAuthentication();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
        }
    }
```

AuthenticationExtensions.cs:

```
public static class AuthenticationExtensions
{

public static IServiceCollection ConfigureAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AuthConstants.DefaultScheme)
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, DefaultSchemeHandler>(AuthConstants.DefaultScheme, AuthConstants.DefaultScheme, null)
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, IdentityAuthenticationHandler>(AuthConstants.IdentityScheme, AuthConstants.IdentityScheme, null);

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("IdentityAuthPolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(AuthConstants.IdentityScheme);
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        });
    });

    return services;
}
```

}

In the controller, I define which authentication schemes to use:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthConstants.IdentityScheme)]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{}
```

Problem: app tries to authenticate with default scheme after failing, tries the one that is specified in authorize attribute. I want the app to use the only authentication scheme that I've defined in authorize attribute. Also, I've tried to use Policy, but the outcome was the same.

Comment: Did you try `AddAuthentication()` without a parameter? And when using the policy, did you use the attribute like this `[Authorize(Policy = "IdentityAuthPolicy")]` ?

Comment: yes i have tried, but then other requests fails to authorize because they don't know how to authorize, and i don't want to set authorize schemes on each controller. With Policy i get the same result.

Comment: Okay, in your `Startup` class `Configure()` method do you add `app.UseAuthorization();` ? You don't see any error logs during your tests?

Comment: Otherwise can you edit your question to include your Startup `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()` methods? (hiding any sensitive info of course)

Comment: Yes i do use app.UseAuthentication(), app.UseAuthorization(). updated the question with startup file.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Add the Controllers Service
2. Set up routing by adding the routing-related middlewares
3. Register the Authorization middleware first by calling 
   `app.UseAuthorization()` before `app.UseAuthentication()`

Here is how your `Startup` class code should like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AuthConstants.DefaultScheme)
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, DefaultSchemeHandler>(AuthConstants.DefaultScheme, AuthConstants.DefaultScheme, null)
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, IdentityAuthenticationHandler>(AuthConstants.IdentityScheme, AuthConstants.IdentityScheme, null);

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("IdentityAuthPolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(AuthConstants.IdentityScheme);
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        });
    });

    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Afterwards, either use the `AuthenticationSchemes` property of the `[Authorize]` attribute or its `Policy` property:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthConstants.IdentityScheme)]
//[Authorize(Policy = "IdentityAuthPolicy")]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Comment: Problem remains the same.

Comment: If that's all the code you have in your `Configure()` method then it's not enough. You don't have a `UseRouting()` before the auth middleware registration and a `UseEndpoints()` after? Is that really all the code you have in that method? middleware registration and the order of that latter is important.

Comment: I updated my answer to give a more complete `Configure()` method as the one you use in your question description is not enough to make the pipeline work correctly.